# OpenCL getDeviceInfo: How to get information about the cores within a CPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

With OpenCL's getDeviceInfo one can get the number of available compute units (CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS). On my nVidia Geforce 8600GTS I have 4 compute units with 8 cores per unit. With getDeviceInfo(...CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS...) I get 4 as answer for the compute units. But, how can I get the information about the number of cores per compute unit?

The OpenCL specification does not give any hint on that subject. Does anyone know how to retrieve the number of core per computation unit in a standard way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way I am aware of - even the underlying CUDA APIs don't presently expose the multiprocessor internal configuration. In the context of OpenCL, where a compute unit might well be the core of a CPU, exposing the internal SIMD configuration via the API doesn't make that much sense, and isn't really all that useful anyway.

NVIDIA do provide the cl_nv_device_attribute_query extension which will give you the CUDA compute capability of the device. This then maps to cores per compute unit as:

```
1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3: 8 cores per execution unit
2.0: 32 cores per execution unit
2.1: 48 cores per execution unit
```

It would be up to you to code this into a subroutine and keep it up to date as hardware changes. Being based on specifics of NVIDIA hardware and relying on an NVIDIA OpenCL extension, all of the above is totally non-portable to other platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I my opinion it would made sense to expose the internal SIMD configuration. For local work group sizes with local memory it would be nice to know the number of core to optimize the work packages.

Comment: @Rick-Rainer Ludwig: The problem is that the number of cores in an NVIDIA or AMD execution unit don't directly relate to the SIMD configuration. In NVIDIA hardware, the SIMD "width" is *always* 32, irrespective of whether the execution unit has 8, 32 or 48 cores. The optimization parameter you should use is the local group size, and you don't set that according to the number of cores in the execution unit - you set it to give the optimal number of warps/wavefronts per execution unit.

Comment: @talonmies: I seem to miss something here. I do a kind of matrix multiplication with shared memory sub matrices for performance optimization. It's very similar to the nVidia oclMatrixMul sample. The shared memory as fas as I understand is located on the CPU and all cores on the CPU have access to it (8 cores on my card) and can therefore used by them. Each sub matrix should be calculated therefore by a CPU with their 8 cores. Different work group are spread over different CPUs, but one work group is on CPU. (I understand an OpenCL programming guide like that.) Am I wrong?

Comment: @Rick-Rainer Ludwig: In a word, yes you are wrong. I can't give you a full answer in the length of a comment - but the underlying execution model of all NVIDIA CUDA/OpenCL capable hardware is that "warps" of 32 threads are executed SIMD style on each multi-processor. In an 8 core MP, the each instruction for a warp gets executed 4 times over the 8 cores to retire for the 32 thread warp. The number of cores is irrelevant to the programming model - each MP needs many warps to cover pipleline latency, and they can come from more than one work group (or CUDA block).

Comment: Thanks. Got it. The warps are not documented so well. Even in official books. ;-) With your hints I found some additional information on that topic and the function clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo which helps me furhter.

Comment: Yep. The rule of thumb now is size 32 warps for NVIDIA and size 64 warps for AMD.